# Sorted() function Python

Tags: python

I have a .txt file with the following lines:

```
pablo 9.50 
sergio 2 
Rose 10 
oto 11.4 
maria 7.9
```

and I have the following program:

```
scores = {}
read = open("C:/Users/renato/Desktop/HTML Files/myfile.txt")
for cont in read: 
    (name,score)=cont.split()
    scores[score] = name
read.close()

print("The top scores are: ")
for eachscore in sorted(scores.keys(), reverse = True):
    print("Surfer "+scores[eachscore]+" scored "+eachscore)
```

When I run the program, it returns the same list, just as seen on the file.

I'm trying to sort the results, hence I used the sorted() function to sort the keys of the 'scores' dictionary. But the entries are being printed in the same order, not sorted as expected.

Am I'm missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: try `scores[name] = float(score)` in line 5 of your code

Comment: He wants the key to be the score and doing `int()` truncates the decimal point.

Comment: the add last line `print("Surfer "+eachscore+" scored "+scores[eachscore])`

Comment: i posted an answer. it may helpful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for them to be ordered on the basis of their float value? Then, you're forgetting a call to `float()`. Without it, the following is the result :

```
>>> scores
{'11.4': 'oto', '10': 'Rose', '9.50': 'pablo', '2': 'sergio', '7.9': 'maria'}
>>> sorted(scores.keys(), reverse = True)
['9.50', '7.9', '2', '11.4', '10']
```

As you can see, the numbers are not ordered (because they are in their string representation), but, calling the `float()` function on them, does the trick.

```
>>> for cont in f:
        (name, score) = cont.split()
        scores[float(score)] = name


>>> scores
{9.5: 'pablo', 2.0: 'sergio', 11.4: 'oto', 10.0: 'Rose', 7.9: 'maria'}
>>> sorted(scores.keys(), reverse = True)
[11.4, 10.0, 9.5, 7.9, 2.0]
```

Now, you can just do -

```
scores = {}
read = open("C:/Users/renato/Desktop/HTML Files/myfile.txt")
for cont in read: 
    (name,score)=cont.split()
    scores[float(score)] = name
read.close()

print("The top scores are: ")
for eachscore in sorted(scores.keys(), reverse = True):
    print("Surfer "+scores[eachscore]+" scored "+str(eachscore))
```

Comment: Thank you! that was it, and to think that this example came from a book!!!! After adding float() as suggested I also needed to add str() to the print statement since it can't concatenate numbers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks Sukrit, great help.

Answer (score 1):

you must not add scores as `dict key`

the problem is :

```
>>> x={'9':'suhail','9':'ta'}
>>> x
{'9': 'ta'}
```

the key overwrites the old

so the best way is use name as `dict key`

```
import operator
scores = {}
read = open("C:/Users/renato/Desktop/HTML Files/myfile.txt")
for cont in read: 
    (name,score)=cont.split()
    scores[name] = float(score)
read.close()

sorted_x = sorted(scores.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print (sorted_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the scores to numbers (otherwise, you would be comparing strings):

```
for eachscore in sorted((float(x) for x in scores.keys()), reverse = True):
    print("Surfer "+scores[eachscore]+" scored "+eachscore)
```